# ¿Porque clase madre no reconoce a clase hija en Python?

Tags: python, clase, herencia, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Tengo la siguiente clase padre

```
class Fruta(object):
    def __init__(self, valor=0):
        self.valor, self.__name__ = valor, "Fruta"

    def __add__(self, otro):  # Operacion = x + 5; ROperacion = 5 + x
        try:
            if self.__class__ == otro.__class__:
                return eval(self.__name__ + "(" + str(self.valor + otro.valor) + ")")
        except:
            raise Excepcion.ErrorSuma(self, otro)
```

Luego la clase hija es la siguiente

```
class Pera(Fruta):
    """Crea la fruta pera."""
    def __init__(self, cantidad=0):
        super(Pera, self).__init__(cantidad)
        self.unidad = "pe"
        self.__name__ = "Pera"
```

Y me arroja este codigo al ejecutarse

```
>>> f = Pera(50)
>>> g = Pera(40)
>>> f + g
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\...........", line 38, in __add__
    return eval(self.__name__ + "(" + str(self.valor + otro.valor) + ")")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Pera' is not defined
```

Pienso que Pera deberia estar en el espacio de nombres porque ese metodo suma se llama a traves de la herencia de la clase hija, ¿Porque no la reconoce?

Comment: Hay varios detalles que aclarar, no es necesario hacer `self.__class__ == otro.__class__`  puedes simplemente usar la metaclase `type`, así `if type(otro)==Pera`.  Por otro lado `super()` inicializará todas las clases padres, no tienes que pasarle la clase Pera. Tampoco es necesario heredar de `object` (en python 3). Tampoco sé que tratas de hacer con el `eval()` si deseas hacer la suma, basta con acceder a los atributos de las clases, sumarlos y retornar la suma, no hay necesidad de usar `eval`. Por último, he probado tu código y no me da error alguno

Comment: En lugar de ejecutar tu código desde la terminal de Python, prueba a añadir estas líneas al final del archivo `.py`, sin indentar: `f = Pera(50)
g = Pera(40)
f + g` y ejecútalo directamente, verás que no hay ningún error de declación; otra cosa diferente es lo que te ha comentado Christian,

Comment: @Christian uso `self.__class__ == otro.__class__` porque si quiero cambiar el nombre del objeto a Perita por ejemplo, no tener que entrar a la clase padre y cambiar manualmente todos los operadores sobrecargados, lo del `super()` tengo entendido que para pasarle el argumento del hijo ese es el procedimiento. Lo del `object` si lo sabia pero luego leí que era una buena practica ponerlo, lo del `eval()` es para que la sume me arroje un objeto `Pera` también en vez de un numero. Si el tuyo ejecuta desde la terminal ¿Crees que sea la versión?, gracias por responder de antemano

Comment: @FranciscoJavier ES que no son dos archivos sueltos, son parte de una librería que estoy haciendo para precisamente poner en practica lo que vaya aprendiendo y que me quede al alcance de unas lineas en la terminal todos mis objetos y funciones y practicar el no repetirme y la herencia y todo eso

Comment: Pero es que Python no puede adivinar dónde se encuentran las clases a instanciar. Desde la terminal tienes que hacer algo así: `from tu_archivo import Fruta, Pera` y luego: `f = Pera(50)   g = Pera(40)   h = f + g   print(h)`, por ejemplo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu enfoque con `eval()`, aunque no es el más correcto (luego doy una alternativa mejor) debería haber funcionado. De hecho lo he probado y funciona. La razón que se me ocurre por la que quizás a ti no te funcionó es que tengas definido en diferentes ficheros las clases `Fruta` y `Pera` (mientras que yo en mi experimento lo hice todo en un solo fichero).

Ocurre que `eval()` recibe en realidad tres parámetros. El primero es la cadena que quieres evaluar. El segundo es un diccionario que contenga todos los símbolos accesibles globalmente, y el tercero es otro diccionario para los símbolos locales. Cuando no proporcionas estos parámetros, se usan por defecto los valores retornados por `globals()` y `locals()` respectivamente.

Por tanto para que tu código funcione, basta que `"Pera"` esté entre los símbolos globales o locales. Cuando todo se ejecuta en un solo fichero estará entre los símbolos globales (pues todas las clases y funciones definidas en ese fichero pasan a ser símbolos globales). Si lo tienes en cambio en otro fichero, es posible que desde la clase "Fruta", el simbolo "Pera" no sea visible por no ser global. Lo mismo da que Pera sea hija de Fruta. La herencia no está relacionada con la visibilidad de los símbolos.

### Solución buena

En todo caso, usar `eval()` es bastante inapropiado cuando hay formas alternativas de hacer lo mismo.

Para empezar, el acceso a la clase de un objeto te lo da `type(objeto)` que es más corto y legible que `objeto.__class__`. En cualquier caso, ambas formas te retornan una referencia a la clase. Puedes usar esa referencia directamente para crear nuevos objetos de esa clase:

```py
clase = type(objeto)
nuevo_objeto = clase(parametros)
```

Con esta idea tu código de Fruta quedaría así (he añadido una función `__repr__()` para ayudar a la depuración):

```py
class Fruta(object):
    def __init__(self, valor=0):
        self.valor, self.__name__ = valor, "Fruta"

    def __add__(self, otro):  # Operacion = x + 5; ROperacion = 5 + x
        if type(self) == type(otro):
            return type(self)(self.valor + otro.valor)
        else:
          raise Excepcion.ErrorSuma(self, otro)
    
    def __repr__(self):
      return f"{type(self).__name__}({self.valor}, name={self.__name__})"
```

(No acabo de entender para qué usas el campo `.__name__`, pero lo he dejado). Esta solución por cierto es inmune a la visibilidad del símbolo "Pera" ya que no usamos para nada ese símbolo. `type(objeto)` te devuelve directamente una referencia a la clase, no una cadena con su nombre, por lo que podemos usar directamente esa referencia desde cualquier espacio de nombres.

La clase `Pera` podría dejarse exactamente igual a como la tenías, pero aprovecho para "mejorar" ligeramente el constructor usando la nueva (no tan nueva ya) sintaxis de `super()` que evita tener que pasarle el nombre de la clase y el objeto:

```py
class Pera(Fruta):
    """Crea la fruta pera."""
    def __init__(self, cantidad=0):
        super().__init__(cantidad)
        self.unidad = "pe"
        self.__name__ = "Pera"
```

#### Demo

```py
>>> p = Pera(50)
>>> q = Pera(40)
>>> p+q
Pera(90, name=Pera)
```

Comment: Efectivamente esta en varios ficheros, usaba el "__name__" para despues usarlo en el `eval()` porque no sabia que lo de la referencia de clases. Hecho eso me lleva a otra pregunta, en caso de que quiera que devuelva un objeto diferente dependiendo del sumando, ¿Como lo haria?, quisiera que si le tengo que sumar manzanas a las peras que devuelva un objeto vegetales

Comment: En ese caso necesitas tener acceso al simbolo `Vegetales`, para poder hacer un `return Vegetales(self.valor + otro.valor)`. La forma de tener acceso a ese símbolo, si está definido en otro fichero, es importarlo. Por ejemplo `from huerta import Vegetales` (siendo `huerta.py` el fichero donde se definiría esa clase)

Comment: Pero esa importación debe ser dentro del método, ¿no?, porque supongamos que lo hago en la parte de arriba en `Fruta` como siempre para que quede global, en ese caso deberia sobre cargar los metodos de `Vegetales`  tambien para que cuando reste la fruta que sea `Pera` o `Manzana` esta operación se efectué, pero al importar `Fruta` en la parte de arriba de `Vegetales` es donde me da error porque comienza un bucle de llamadas entre las clases que no se detiene

Answer (score 0):

La manera correcta de hacerlo es:

```
class Fruta(object):
    def __init__(self, valor=0):
        self.valor = valor
```

De la clase `Fruta` sólo necesitas almacenar su valor; el nombre es simplemente una constante en el código, que no necesitas almacenar como parte del objeto. En último caso, el nombre de clase es una atributo de la clase, no del objeto.

La operación de suma la tienes muy complicada. Basta con

```
def __add__(self, otro):  # Operacion = x + 5; ROperacion = 5 + x
    if isinstance(otro, Fruta):
        return self.valor + otro.valor
    else:
        raise ErrorSuma(self, otro)
```

Si preguntas si las clases son iguales, entonces no podrás sumar los valores de peras y manzanas.

La pregunta correcta es si el otro operando es Fruta o subclase, pues todas deben traer el atributo `valor`, los que simplemente sumo. Si hay algún error numérico, se levantará una excepción, que el llamante tendrá que manejar.

class Pera(Fruta):
"""Crea la fruta pera."""
def **init**(self, cantidad=0):
super().**init**(cantidad)
self.unidad = "pe"

#### Demo

```
class Fruta(object):
    def __init__(self, valor=0):
        self.valor = valor

    def __add__(self, otro):  # Operacion = x + 5; ROperacion = 5 + x
        if isinstance(otro, Fruta):
            return self.valor + otro.valor
        else:
            raise ErrorSuma(self, otro)

class Pera(Fruta):
    """Crea la fruta pera."""
    def __init__(self, cantidad=0):
        super().__init__(cantidad)
        self.unidad = "pe"

f = Pera(50)
g = Pera(40)
a = f + g
print(a)
```

produce:

```
90

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Pregunto los tipos para que tenga diferente comportamiento si le sumo peras o manzanas, en caso de sumarse con peras que devuelva un objeto pera, pero al sumarse con manzanas que devuelva un objeto totalmente nuevo, como por ejemplo "vegetales", en ese caso ¿como pudiera lograrlo?